# Qt QTextEdit Qt4.2 Valid HTML String

Tags: html, qt, qtextedit

I am trying to generate the correct HTML to render to a QTextEdit Using Qt 4.2 on RHEL 5.3. 
So far my algorithm generates the following html. I am not an expert web developer, but to me this string seems valid.

```
319:14:27:22:   <font color="rgb(255,0,0)" bgcolor="rgb(255,0,0)">Message</font><br>
```

What needs to change to get the colours to render. Currently it just renders as black text on a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTextEdit accepts *a subset* of HTML detailed [here in the doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html).

For font color attribute, it must be "Qt color names or #RRGGBB".